# How do I install developer apps to a Now TV box

Tags: installation, roku

How do I install developer apps to a Now TV box, including standard apps that aren't normally available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your NowTV remote enter the following combination:

```
Home, Home, Home, Up, Up, Right, Left, Right, Left, Right
```

If you did correctly, you will be presented with developer mode.

1. Make a note of the IP address and username.
2. Accept the Terms and conditions.
3. Set your password.

This allows you to login to your NowTV box using the IP and username displayed on the developer presentation screen.

This also allows you to install a media streamer software such as the popular Plex-based, "RARflix" app - https://github.com/ljunkie/rarflix/raw/master/RARflix.zip.

***Important note:*** Only one developer app is allowed to be installed at once.

Comment: By "Only one developer app is allowed to be installed at once", do you mean one at a time?

Comment: I'm unsure why it was designed this way, but when you've installed app1 and you later decide to install app2 then you have to uninstall app1 before you can install app2. Only one app can be installed at one time. The box does come with some other apps already loaded onto it e.g. Youtube, iPlayer, itvplayer, etc. but there are a few missing e.g. Amazon and Netflix.

Comment: Thanks, KN. I've been messing around with my box and, yeah, there's no obvious way to work around it. I guess code from multiple apps could be combined. I read somewhere (I'm sure it's in Google) that there is a 2 MB limit for the developer app. The Rarflix app is around 800 kb, for example, so there's a decent amount of space (I think).

Comment: Wow. Considering an old Amiga floppy disc capacity was 880kb, that's not a lot. It's about the size of the first Sonic the Hedgehog game on the Megadrive.

Comment: Very true. The newer Rokus might have a lot more space but I imagine the apps would want to be backwards compatible. I think they're considered "web apps" so that most of the effort is done by the servers for that particular app. It would be nice for the clients (which are usually very powerful) to do the work, but hey ho!